# parse text file into sparse matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, file, parsing, sparse-matrix

I have a text file in the form of:

```
10244:3668 4 3663 4 2386 4 4228 3 2361 3 1292 4 2233 4 1945 3 523 4 2695 4 3658 4 1126 4
10269:1949 1 1073 3 450 3 987 3 34 5 2916 4 805 4 2695 3 4467 4 2473 4 
10421:395 3 2969 5 464 5 2667 1 157 4 118 4 3898 4 4466 3 2034 3 176 2 3304 2 
...
```

This represents a rating matrix where each line represents one user's ratings. The user id and the items the user has rated are separated by `:`. So the first number on each line is the `user_id` and each successive pair of numbers to the right of `:` is a pair of **item code** and **item rating**.

I would like to parse this file using matlab and create a sparse matrix using this. Although I know how to create the sparse matrix, I am very new to matlab and have no idea how to parse this file so as to have entries in the form:

```
user_id, item_id, rating
```

for each rating in the file.

---

**Example:**

First line:

```
10244:3668 4 3663 4 2386 4 4228 3 2361 3 1292 4 2233 4 1945 3 523 4 2695 4 3658 4 1126 4
```

would be transformed into:

```
10244,3668,4
10244,3663,4
10244,2386,4
10244,4228,3
...
```

I feel this is quite a simple task in languages like python where file parsing is very versatile but I am unable to figure out how to do this in matlab as I started working with matlab only this week. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at `textscan`, it allows multiple delimiters: `ln=textscan(x,'%d',inf,'Delimiter',{':',' '})`

Comment: I converted my text file to the form row col value\n   and I used textscan function as follows:                                       ln = textscan(f,'%d %d %f',inf,'Delimiter',{' '});                     and now I have values ln{1},ln{2},ln{3} of class int32 and am unable to create a sparse matrix out of these because the method sparse does not taken in values of type int32. How would I convert these into list or vector objects which ever sparse function accepts?

Comment: Convert the values to double, using the `double` function.